# using selenium with python on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu-14.04

I want to automate the navigation of a page, scan its QR code and then interact with it.

I am doing this with selenium and python.

But I don't see any display to scan the QR code,

this is how my code begins:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

What shall I do to see the display and scan QR code and resume the program?

I read examples of using Selenium on Windows in which the browser shows up automatically.

Comment: Is this a headless server? What happens when the last line executes?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using a virtual display ( i.e. headless browser ), remove these two lines and you must be able to see the browser.

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Since you don't need the virtual display, remove the first line as well.